# Aeson decode rounding by scientific notion

Tags: haskell, yesod, aeson

thanks for reading this , I've been struggled for a while I'm using Aeson/TH to auto generate the `fromJSON/toJSON` of a ADT. I'm using `Yesod` to accept data from HTTP call .

```
import Data.Aeson hiding (json)
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Data.Aeson.TH
import Data.Aeson.Types

data Money = USD Float
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Money)

.... -- getting request from HTTP
_money <- requireCheckJsonBody :: Handler Money
```

The issue is that , if I pass a large nubmer in `Money` like `USD 1157265240.03`, but the `_money` will have float value of `1,157,265,300.0` which rounds `240` to `300`.

this looks like caused by a conversion from String alike  `Scientific notation` to a Float which will trancate the tail part of number.

Any idea how to bypass such conversion which cause loss of precision ? Thanks

[image]

Comment: The underlying `Float` value is probably correct, it's just being printed back at lower precision. This is moot: you should *never* use floats for money. Write a custom parser or whatever and read the value as an integer number of cents or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of precision has nothing to do with yesod or aeson, but instead with your choice of `Float` as a datatype. Type `1157265240.03 :: Float` at the GHCi prompt, and you'll get `1.1572653e9` back. IEEE single-precision floats can't represent amounts more accurately than that once the magnitude gets that high. (Specifically, the only number between 1,157,265,152.00 and 1,157,265,408.00 that a single-precision float can hold is 1,157,265,280.00.) You need a different datatype. Aeson internally stores JSON numbers using [the `Scientific` datatype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.7.0/docs/Data-Scientific.html#t:Scientific), which is arbitrary precision. Another reasonable choice would be [`Centi` from `Data.Fixed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Centi).

Comment: Even using a better type internally will fail when serializing to a JSON number, when they get big enough. Unfortunately, the only usable format JSON provides for large numbers is string.

Comment: @Carl When exactly would that be a problem? I just did a quick test with an absurdly big and precise number, and it got serialized exactly: `ghci> encode (Array [Number 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345])
"[1.234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345e59]"`

Comment: The spec only requires numbers be double-precision. If you're involving any other software, you're at the mercy of how it parses and serializes numbers. Lots of parsers fail at even getting doubles right. That aeson happens to ignore the spec and be more useful is no proof anything else will do the same.

Comment: @Carl Can you quote the relevant part of the spec? I read through json.org, ECMA-404, and ISO/IEC 21778:2017, and I didn't see anything in any of them mandating double-precision.

Comment: json.org says that json is a subset of ECMA-262 3rd Edition. ECMA-262 3rd Edition section 4.3.20 says "In ECMAScript, the set of values represents the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values".

Comment: @Carl It doesn't say it *is* a subset of that. It says it's *based on* a subset of that. And ECMA-404 specifically says "it does not
attempt to impose ECMAScript’s internal data representations on other programming languages."

Comment: @Carl Also, ECMA-404 says this: "JSON is agnostic about the semantics of numbers. In any programming language, there can be a variety of
number types of various capacities and complements, fixed or floating, binary or decimal. That can make
interchange between different programming languages difficult. JSON instead offers only the representation of
numbers that humans use: a sequence of digits. All programming languages know how to make sense of digit
sequences even if they disagree on internal representations. That is enough to allow interchange."

Comment: @monica It may be a different question ,but how to convert a `Centi` type to `Float` ? I've been search the package but the closest thing I can find is `fromIntegral . round $ 1000.54::Fixed E2` but it will rounds and lost the precision.

Comment: @ShawnZhang If you want to store the number 1,157,265,240.03 accurately, then you must never have it stored as a `Float`. Why do you think you need to convert to or from `Float`?

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica  the idea is , that the balance is a E2 , and there is a interest rate which is a `float` , I want to multile them like ` (0.025::Float) * 1000.54::Fixed E2` , which will raise an error . I need to convert balance to `Float` to multiply with the `rate` which is a Float.

Comment: @ShawnZhang Don't do the math in the `Float` type. Do it in `Scientific` or `Rational` or something instead.

Comment: Don't use `Scientific` for anything other than serialization. Arithmetic on it will diverge if it results in something without an exact representation in base 10. Don't use `Rational` for financial computations either, its memory use is unbounded for any particular magnitude of number. That will strike in surprising ways when doing things like applying compound interest computations. And definitely don't use `Float` or `Double`. The [Centi](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Centi) type (or others) in `Data.Fixed` is reasonable, though.